# Use PHP in XML page for rss

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss

I would like to know if it is possible to use Php coding in a xml page that is used for rss.
Basically I want to connect to mysql database and pull out information to be in the rss feed as shown;

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($sql_rss)){

    $post_title = $r->title;
    $post_post = $r->thepost;
    $post_link = $r->thelink;

    $received_posts .= '
<title>'.$post_title.'</title>
<link>'.$post_link.'</link>
<description>'.$post_post.'</description>';
```

Would I need to do anything special to use php in a xml script?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure that the server is processing the file for PHP directives (probably by using `.php` on the end of the filename) and set the Content-Type (since it defaults to HTML).

```
header('Content-Type: application/rss+xml');
```

Comment: But i have to use .xml to make it a valid rss feed

Comment: No. Content-type matters in HTTP resources, they don't have file extensions (although they might have things which map on to file extensions on files).

Comment: so make a php script like above and then in the beginning of the page just put the content-type?

Comment: http://mattyc.com/rss/feed.php now I just echo the results but instead it prints it out as text on the screen instead of xml

Comment: That's your browser's doing. Look at the source. It's working! (though you'll want to get rid of that '<a href="' business so that it validates).

Comment: You have errors. http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmattyc.com%2Frss%2Ffeed.php Looks like you are making the classic error of building XML by bashing together strings instead of using an XML library.